# Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) - "data" Array Documentation

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Google doesn't have a documentation that describes the content of the `data` array, as far as I can see.
I can only find the standard documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html).

Where is the official documentation for this?
e.g. "title" for the title to show in the push notification.

Beside that, I'm trying to show the user image like WhatsApp does, and I didn't find anything about that.

A documentation would be helpful, and I didn't find anything on the net about that.